# Will a dweller ever leave when sitting outside of the vault?

Tags: fallout-shelter

This is merely a question of curiosity as I currently have one dweller who's been sitting outside of the vault for a solid four days. My vault runs efficiently and everyone is happy. As new arrivals make their appearance to the vault, I usually place them where they'll be most effective.

Four days ago, this dweller with a charisma of 3 and all other stats of 1, doesn't serve much of a purpose within my flourishing underground community (yet.) So he sits patiently.

My question is: is there a point in time where a dweller will give up trying to enter the vault and return to the wasteland? Or, will he sit there forever with a smile on his face?